# How to extract text from URL in cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to return the highlighted text based on the image below. I think the error is based on the location of the character.

[image]

This is the error I incur.

> Error: Function MID parameter 3 value is negative. It should be
> positive or zero.

This is what I have so far:

```
=mid(B2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/",CHAR(1),3))+1,find(char(1),SUBSTITUTE(B2,"-",char(1),1))
- find(char(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),1))-1)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will find that there are many ways to solve your problem. This answer uses an 'old school' method:

`=mid(B2,(find("/",B2,(find("Box+",B2))+1))+1,(find("-",B2,(find("Box+",B2))+1))-(find("/",B2,(find("Box+",B2))+1))-1)`

Answer (score 1):

As per your screenshot data, you can try-

```
=INDEX(CHOOSECOLS(SPLIT(CHOOSECOLS(SPLIT(A2:A10,"box+1/",0),2),"/"),1))
```

[image]